# shinyloadtest using R

Tags: r, shiny, pandoc, shinydashboard

I am trying to have the load test and performance testing of my new shiny app which I am planning to host on our local server (interoffice application).

I have landed up on a forum which suggested to have the load test done using **shinyloadtest** package, wherein i was able to do the following:

1. record session
2. loadruns with 100 workers successfully.
3. able to create a dataframe of loadruns.

However, in order to create a report, we have to run the command **shinyloadtest_report**(df, "report.html") with which i am getting an error:

**Error: Please upgrade your pandoc version to be at least v2.2**

i had tried upgrading the pandoc version using r installr (install.pandoc()) but unable to do so because of following error:"this version is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher." with windows 10.

1. Anyone also landed on the same situation?
2. Is there any other way we can upgrade pandoc specific version?
3. Any other solution for loadtesting of interoffice shiny app hosted on local server?

Answer (score 1):

You can either 
1) upgrade RStudio to v1.2+ Preview version: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ because Pandoc 2.x is built in there.

or
2) install Pandoc yourself, by following https://pandoc.org/installing.html

My solution was 2) but because I am on macOS, I don't have experience with Windows 10 just yet but I presume it will work if you follow the instruction.